# how to load single docker image from tar ball which contains multiple docker images

Tags: docker

`docker load -i myTarFile.tar` loads all the images inside the tar
`myTarFile.tar`.

Contains two images :

- `k8s.gcr.io/cloud-controller-manager`
- `gcr.io/google_containers/cloud-controller-manager:v1.11.1`

I want to load only `gcr.io/google_containers/cloud-controller-manager:v1.11.1`

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any dependency between these two images?

Comment: no there is no dependancy, actually, our product ships multiple images  into single images. and i need to load only perticular image from bundled multiple images.